# Monodevelop not recompiling changes

Tags: c#, monodevelop, unity-game-engine, macos-sierra

Un Unity3d, I am having an issue where changes to Code (C#, Monodevelop) is not picked up, until I reload the Project or Reimport all assets.

The (Intermittent) problem seems to start when I write something with a compile time error.  After that point, any changes to the file are ignored (the old error still appears when you try to Build again).  Even commenting out the line, or adding other errors on purpose.

It seems to happen once or twice an hour.

Unity 5.5.0f3 64 bit on Mac.

Does anyone know a fix?
Can anyone suggest next steps to debug the compilation process?

Comment: TBH I'd use another IDE like https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/. I've watched a lot of official Unity tutorials where Mono has let them down live in front of the audience ;)

Comment: I suppose Im trying to keep monodevelop as the official tutorials use it and it makes it easier to follow when you use the exact same toolset!
Think I will end up switching though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this, upgrading to 5.5.1 once released fixes the problem.